# Python 3.x How extract alphabetic representation of numbers from string

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, text, nltk

I need to parse text that may contain alphabetical numbers. For example

```
"I`ve got sixty six tasks"
```

or

```
"There is four people"
```

My goal is get substring `sixty six` and `four`

In internet a lot of approaches when converting number string representation to integer, without additional texts. But i need to next result:

```
find_numbers("Hello world") -> []
find_numbers("Hello five world") -> ['five']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 libraries for this:

- [word2number](https://pypi.org/project/word2number/)
- [num2words](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words)

`word2number` will extract the number from the string.

e.g.

```
>>> print(w2n.word_to_num("Hello five world"))
5
```

You can then use the `num2words` library to convert the output back to a word:

```
>>> print(num2words(5))
five
```

Comment: It's not fit because if i have string `i have three apples and two bananas` w2n return 5

Comment: @БогданМарченко What's the constraints for the number? e.g. is there a maximum? e.g. not above 10

Comment: it may be different numbers, like `one`, `sixty six`, `three million`, `three hundred twenty eight`

Answer (score 0):

Since I was bored, I modified a version of `word_to_num`. Some of the error checking isn't included but you can add that in if you want to.

I'm not going to go into too much detail on how it works, but essentially, it splits the numbers into groups and then feeds each of those groups into `word2number`s algorithm.

```
american_number_system = {
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19,
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90,
    'hundred': 100,
    'thousand': 1000,
    'million': 1000000,
    'billion': 1000000000
}


def number_formation(number_words):
    numbers = []
    for number_word in number_words:
        numbers.append(american_number_system[number_word])
    if len(numbers) == 4:
        return (numbers[0] * numbers[1]) + numbers[2] + numbers[3]
    elif len(numbers) == 3:
        return numbers[0] * numbers[1] + numbers[2]
    elif len(numbers) == 2:
        if 100 in numbers:
            return numbers[0] * numbers[1]
        else:
            return numbers[0] + numbers[1]
    else:
        return numbers[0]

def get_decimal_sum(decimal_digit_words):
    decimal_number_str = []
    for dec_word in decimal_digit_words:
        if(dec_word not in decimal_words):
            return 0
        else:
            decimal_number_str.append(american_number_system[dec_word])
    final_decimal_string = '0.' + ''.join(map(str,decimal_number_str))
    return float(final_decimal_string)

def to_num(string):
    string = string.replace('-', ' ')
    string = string.replace(',', ' ')
    words = string.strip().split()

    number_groups = []
    current_word = []
    numbers = []

    for word in words:
        if word in american_number_system:
            current_word.append(word)
        elif word.lower() != 'and' and len(current_word):
            number_groups.append(current_word)
            current_word = []
    
    if len(current_word):
        number_groups.append(current_word)

    for clean_numbers in number_groups:
        clean_decimal_numbers = []
        total_sum = 0

        if clean_numbers.count('point') == 1:
            clean_decimal_numbers = clean_numbers[clean_numbers.index('point')+1:]
            clean_numbers = clean_numbers[:clean_numbers.index('point')]

        billion_index = clean_numbers.index('billion') if 'billion' in clean_numbers else -1
        million_index = clean_numbers.index('million') if 'million' in clean_numbers else -1
        thousand_index = clean_numbers.index('thousand') if 'thousand' in clean_numbers else -1

        if len(clean_numbers) == 1:
                total_sum += american_number_system[clean_numbers[0]]

        else:
            if billion_index > -1:
                billion_multiplier = number_formation(clean_numbers[0:billion_index])
                total_sum += billion_multiplier * 1000000000

            if million_index > -1:
                if billion_index > -1:
                    million_multiplier = number_formation(clean_numbers[billion_index+1:million_index])
                else:
                    million_multiplier = number_formation(clean_numbers[0:million_index])
                total_sum += million_multiplier * 1000000

            if thousand_index > -1:
                if million_index > -1:
                    thousand_multiplier = number_formation(clean_numbers[million_index+1:thousand_index])
                elif billion_index > -1 and million_index == -1:
                    thousand_multiplier = number_formation(clean_numbers[billion_index+1:thousand_index])
                else:
                    thousand_multiplier = number_formation(clean_numbers[0:thousand_index])
                total_sum += thousand_multiplier * 1000

            if thousand_index > -1 and thousand_index != len(clean_numbers)-1:
                hundreds = number_formation(clean_numbers[thousand_index+1:])
            elif million_index > -1 and million_index != len(clean_numbers)-1:
                hundreds = number_formation(clean_numbers[million_index+1:])
            elif billion_index > -1 and billion_index != len(clean_numbers)-1:
                hundreds = number_formation(clean_numbers[billion_index+1:])
            elif thousand_index == -1 and million_index == -1 and billion_index == -1:
                hundreds = number_formation(clean_numbers)
            else:
                hundreds = 0
            total_sum += hundreds
        
        if len(clean_decimal_numbers) > 0:
            decimal_sum = get_decimal_sum(clean_decimal_numbers)
            total_sum += decimal_sum
        
        numbers.append(total_sum)
    
    return numbers

tests = []
tests.append(to_num("I`ve got sixty six tasks"))
tests.append(to_num("There is four people"))
tests.append(to_num("Hello world"))
tests.append(to_num("Hello five world"))
tests.append(to_num("i have three apples and two bananas"))
tests.append(to_num("three hundred twenty eight"))

print(tests)
```

From here you could just use `num2words` to reverse the result.

Edit:

Actually, rereading your question, it's much easier than that. you just need to find the positions of those numbers and extract those.

```
american_number_system = {
    'zero': 0,
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
    'three': 3,
    'four': 4,
    'five': 5,
    'six': 6,
    'seven': 7,
    'eight': 8,
    'nine': 9,
    'ten': 10,
    'eleven': 11,
    'twelve': 12,
    'thirteen': 13,
    'fourteen': 14,
    'fifteen': 15,
    'sixteen': 16,
    'seventeen': 17,
    'eighteen': 18,
    'nineteen': 19,
    'twenty': 20,
    'thirty': 30,
    'forty': 40,
    'fifty': 50,
    'sixty': 60,
    'seventy': 70,
    'eighty': 80,
    'ninety': 90,
    'hundred': 100,
    'thousand': 1000,
    'million': 1000000,
    'billion': 1000000000
}

def extract_num(raw_string):
    string = raw_string.replace('-', ' ')
    string = string.replace(',', ' ')
    words = string.strip().split()

    word_pos = False
    numbers = []
    current_pos = 0

    for word in words:
        if word in american_number_system:
            if word_pos:
                length = len(word) + 1
                word_pos = (word_pos[0], word_pos[1] + length)
            else:
                length = len(word)
                word_pos = (current_pos, current_pos + length)
        elif word.lower() == 'and' and word_pos:
            word_pos = (word_pos[0], word_pos[1] + 4)
        elif word_pos:
            numbers.append(raw_string[word_pos[0]:word_pos[1]])
            word_pos = False
        
        current_pos += len(word) + 1
    
    if word_pos:
        numbers.append(raw_string[word_pos[0]:])
    
    return numbers


tests = []
tests.append(extract_num("I`ve got sixty six tasks"))
tests.append(extract_num("There is four people"))
tests.append(extract_num("Hello world"))
tests.append(extract_num("Hello five world"))
tests.append(extract_num("i have three apples and two bananas"))
tests.append(extract_num("three hundred twenty eight"))

print(tests)
```